# Dispatch_once singleton error objective c

Tags: objective-c, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

I am relatively new to GCD, I am currently using it to create a singleton object in my application. After doing some research I found using GCD's dispatch_once() method is the best way to achieve the singleton design pattern. For some reason, my code is breaking and I can not figure it out for the life of me. Below, I have pasted my singleton creation/init code, and the responding error.

```
+(id)sharedErrorMapper {

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
static id sharedInstance;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedInstance;

}

-(id)init {
//creating the ErrorMap data structure
//currently loading in dummy JSON data..
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSData *resourceData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                        @"/Users/acuram/Desktop/GitHubWorkspaces/ios-sdk-src/ios-here-sdk/PPHSDKTests/Resources"];
    self.errorMap = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    self.errorMap = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:resourceData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
return self;
}
```

After setting some breakpoints and doing some stack tracing, my code is breaking at the dispatch_once() function call. The error I get back is a "NSInvalidArgumentException", it complains that my data parameter is nil. I am pretty shocked because I followed a legit tutorial video on youtube to implement this, I am also looking at my companies code base and they seem to do it in a similar way....

Comment: Your `dispatch_once` code looks fine. Try commenting out the code inside the `if` in your designated initializer, and see if the error goes away after that.

Comment: damn that did the trick, I am pretty ashamed of myself for that one. Thanks man

Comment: Was not giving the full path to my file, so NSData was nil, then I was trying to unpack a nill JSON object when setting self.errorMap, so shit went all haywire